# "variable invitationId of type Int! is used in position expecting Int_comparison_exp"

Tags: postgresql, graphql, hasura

I was trying following query on hasura platform and it gave below error. 
I got solution for the same. That's why I'm sharing.
variables:

```
     {
          "invaId": 791
       }
```

---

Query:

```
    mutation UpdateQuery($status:String!,$invaId:Int!) {
      update_inva(_set: {status: $status},where:{id:$invaId}){
         affected_rows
      }
    }
```

---

```
Output:
```

```
{
  "errors": [
    {
      "extensions": {
        "path": "$.selectionSet.update_inva.args.where.id",
        "code": "validation-failed"
      },
      "message": "variable invaId of type Int! is used in position expecting Int_comparison_exp"
    }
  ]
}
```

```
I faced this error after passing the variable of type Int!.
```

Answer (score 4):

The problem is in query.

Look at the where clause

`where:{id:$invitationId})`

where clause expects the comparison type too for eg.  **_eq**.

That was the exact thing which I was missing.

So, I updated the query as below, and things were running perfectly

Query:

```
mutation UpdateQuery($status:String!,$invaId:Int!) {
  update_inva(_set: {status: $status},where:{id:{_eq:$invaId}}){
    affected_rows
  }
}
```